# How to delete all elements from a list while in recursion?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm currently trying to write a predicate which can turn any list of integers into a bunch of "parity runs" where each run is a (maximal) sequence of consecutive even or odd numbers within the original list.

For example, the list

List = [8,0,4,3,7,2,-1,9,9]

can be broken into [8, 0, 4], [3, 7], [2] and [-1, 9, 9]

What I'm trying to do is to recursively scan through the list and append the integers one by one into a list called OldList. The program will keep appending integers until a number of the opposite polarity (odd or even) is appended which then the OldList will create a new list called TinyList containing 1 parity run. This separate parity run is then appended onto the resulting output list. What I'm having trouble is reseting the OldList after successfully completing 1 parity run. I'm trying to turn OldList to an empty list so that I can keep doing more parity runs but I'm having no luck. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
% base case
paruns([], [], []).

% recursive case
paruns([Head|Tail], OldList, RunList):-
paruns(Tail, TempList, SubList),               

% appending each integer to the OldList
append([Head], TempList, OldList),.

% returns a parity run when polarity of number changes or returns nothing
createTinyList(OldList, TinyList),

/*
Trying to reset OldList here <-------------------- but no luck :(
*/

% appends 1 parity run list into the final output list
append(TinyList, SubList, RunList).



% checks if number is odd
    odd(Num):-
    1 is Num mod 2.

% checks if number is even
    even(Num):-
    0 is Num mod 2.

% checks if the polarity of 1st and 2nd numbers are same
% returns [] if both numbers have same polarity
% if 1st and 2nd numbers have different polarity this predicate will output the whole list, excluding the 1st number with different polarity
createTinyList([Head|[]],[]).

createTinyList([Head|[MiniHead|Tail]], []):-
    odd(Head), odd(MiniHead).

createTinyList([Head|[MiniHead|Tail]], []):-
    even(Head), even(MiniHead).

createTinyList([Head|[MiniHead|Tail]], [MiniHead|Tail]):-
    odd(Head), even(MiniHead).

createTinyList([Head|[MiniHead|Tail]], [MiniHead|Tail]):-
    even(Head), odd(MiniHead).
```

Whenever I mention polarity, assume I'm talking about the oddness or evenness of a number.

Comment: Say the first number is odd, should the result start with an empty list? Like `[[],[3,7]]`?

Comment: In Prolog variables are not set, they are bound and once bound can not be changed. If you are thinking like an imperative programmer you will have problems using Prolog. You need to forget about imperative programming with using a logic language such as Prolog. If you know how functional languages work with binding values, then you are on the right path.

Comment: Willem the result would simply be [[3,7]] without the empty list